# how to store [[string]] and get it from core data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, transformable

I have sample array of [[string]] like this [["A", "B", "C"], ["A"], ["B", "C"], ["C"], ["B"], ["B", "C", "A"]]

I store it to core data like this :

```
insertHeroes.setValue(roless, forKey: "roles")
```

which roless is array result from API (after append loop) with `var roless = [[String]]()`

core data is stored in list `var coreHeroList: [NSManagedObject] = []`

but when I try to get from core data and store it (after removeall) like this :

```
if (coreHeroList.count > 0) {
            for hero in coreHeroList {
                roless.append(hero.value(forKey: "roles") as? [[String]] ?? [[""]])
            }
        }
```

it give red error : Cannot convert value of type '[[String]]' to expected argument type '[String]'

My transformable is like this :
[image]

I set core data to manual and already set NSManagedObject SubClass

How to get [[string]] from core data? Does my insert to core data wrong?

Comment: Why not make an entity Role?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `[[String]]` is being stored in CoreData correctly.  The problem is that you are trying to append it directly to `roless`: you can append things of type `[String]`, but you can't *append* things of type `[[String]]`.  You can, however, merge them:

```
roless += hero.value(forKey: "roles") as? [[String]] ?? [[""]]
```

But I agree with @JoakimDanielson's comment: it might be wise to create a `Role` entity and model a to-many relationship rather than handle transformables.

Comment: if I follow roless += hero.value(forKey: "roles") as? [[String]] ?? [[""]], it will print all empty array, but after I try with this roless.append(hero.value(forKey: "roles") as? [String] ?? [""]), it got all saved array value